# Neo4J: GC overhead limit exceeded when creating relationship

Tags: neo4j

code is:

```
load csv with headers from "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/feu5-w2e2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD" as row
create (n:Contact) set n=row;

load csv with headers from "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/tesw-yqqr/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD" as row
create (n:Building) set n=row;

create index on :Contact(RegistrationID);

create index on :Building(RegistrationID);
```

Then when I try and create a relationship it goes up to like 8GB ram and eventually times out and the application dies using this:

```
MATCH (b:Building),(c:Contact)
where b.RegistrationID = c.RegistrationID
create (b)-[:CONTACTS_FOR]->(c)
```

Windows 7/64 bit i7-3770, 32GB ram...

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is large, you don't want to perform any query that operates over an entire label, you're almost guaranteed to see memory spike, timeout, and eventually an OutOfMemory error in the neo4j logs. The order you should perform those queries in is:

1) Make the indexes.

2) Merge one of the datasets and merge the relationships *in advance* like so, and use periodic commit so that you don't have to hold the whole result in memory [EDIT: Since RegistrationID is not a unique property, create a stand-in node for it, so that part of your relationship can be pre-built]:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
load csv with headers from "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/tesw-yqqr/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD" as row
CREATE (b:Building) SET b=row
MERGE (i:RegistrationID {RegistrationID: row.RegistrationID})
MERGE (b) - [:CONTACTS_FOR] -> (i)
```

3) Then, merge in the other data set. Your existing index will make sure that if you use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`, you'll get the RegistrationID nodes that are already created that you returned in your last step:

```
USING PERIOD COMMIT 500
load csv with headers from "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/feu5-w2e2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD" as row
CREATE (c:Contact) SET c = row
MERGE (i:RegistrationID {RegistrationID: row.RegistrationID})
MERGE (i) - [:CONTACT_FOR] -> (c)
```

To query contacts by building then, use the * operator like so:

```
MATCH (b:Building) WHERE <whatever conditions you want>
WITH b
MATCH (b) <- [:CONTACT_FOR*2] - (c)
RETURN c
```

Now, if your data's already in and you don't want to reload, you'll have to use SKIP and LIMIT on your query to only process a chunk at a time:

```
MATCH (b:Building)
WITH b
SKIP 0
LIMIT 500
MATCH (c:Contact) WHERE c._id = b._id
MERGE (b) - [:CONTACTS_FOR] -> (c)
```

and then run it repeatedly, moving SKIP and LIMIT up by 500 each time.

Even if your machine is theoretically capable of handling that large a query, there are limits set by both neo4j *and* the JVM it runs on that may prevent you from leveraging it. Try to come up with a solution that uses lots of little iterative queries instead of one big one, it's usually a lot more effective.

Comment: This is very helpful and worked very quickly. How would I also add a merge on the second load for contacts for rows that have the same values on (FirstName, LastName) and (BusinessHouseNumber,BusinessStreetName, BusinessApartment, BusinessCity) tuples?

Comment: This will connect your `(c:Contact)` to other `(:Contact)`s that share those properties:
`MERGE (d:Contact {FirstName: c.FirstName, LastName: c.LastName}) MERGE (c) - [:IS] -> (d)`
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Something like that, I think that will work or at least sets me on the right path but the issue again is memory/performance. I am starting to think that I have to give up on neo4J because it takes too long and is incredibly memory inefficient for my needs :(

Comment: Put a `PERIODIC COMMIT 500` at the top of the second load too, I left that out. neo4j is very performant, but it requires fairly active memory management; if you can break your query up into steps (using `PERIODIC COMMIT` during loads, or `SKIP...LIMIT` during other iterative queries), absolutely do so, the slightly increased transaction cost is easily covered by the increased efficiency.

Comment: I really want to build the following relationships: Buildings have one-to-many relationship to contacts, join condition registrationID = registrationID. Then contacts have many-to-one relationship back to buildings with same join condition. Then finally contacts have relationship to other contacts where either first and last name is the same OR mailing address items are the same OR both of those. Is there any way to build this without waiting a billion years? :)

Comment: I _think_ this does the first part:

using periodic commit 500 load csv with headers from "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/feu5-w2e2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD" as row 
match (b:Building {RegistrationID: row.RegistrationID})
match (c:Contact {RegistrationID: row.RegistrationID})
merge (c)-[:CONTACTS_OF]->(b)
merge (b)-[:CONTACT_FOR]->(c)

Comment: OK this is mostly there I think. I still need a way to MERGE contacts based on matching addresses. Can I do that at the same time in the second step? It would be matches on (BusinessHouseNumber,BusinessStreetName,BusinessApartment,BusinessZip)